# How to create range slider (Angular Material) in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

As a default, there is no range slider in Angular Material. Are there any ways use range slider in Angular 4?

Comment: This is an open issue - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/1331

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for me https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-nouislider the best for Angular 4.

Comment: actually, you have to rebuild each time if you have conflicting npm's be cautious.

Comment: After some research I realized that it is the best, indeed. Thanks.

Comment: I think its no longer a better option for higher versions of Angular i.e., 8 and 9 etc.

Answer (score 8):

**Angular 8 and above**

I was facing the same issue of creating a range slider in angular material. And I just found it. [image: Preview of solution]

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-range-slider-kxqxmq) is the stackblitz code snippet of solution which is not mine but its awesome.

And [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng5-slider) is the link to ng5-slider package which is used in the above example. ng5-slider is the Angular version(2 or above) of [rzslider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider)

Answer (score 1):

[image]use my range slider its based on material angular slider libry and its modifyd by me  repository have simple angular 7 application with sample range slider https://github.com/dinukasaminda/angular-material-range-slider